# Is it possible to make the if statement change one img to another slowly?

Tags: javascript

This is a simple JS function: `onclick` will check certain divs and replace the images in these divs.

My question: Can I regulate the transition time between the images using only JS ?

Thank you!

```
function menu() {
    if (document.getElementById("contactus").getAttribute('src') ==
        "images/mainpage/image1.png") {
        document.getElementById("contactus").src =
            "images/mainpage/image2.png";
    }
}
```

Comment: perhaps this thread would help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23583245/add-transition-while-changing-img-src-with-javascript

Comment: You can probably try using CSS transition property. That will allow you to simply adjust the effect using CSS without modifying your current javascript code.

Comment: As per the @JkAlombro 's suggested link, this is possible through the jquery `toggelClass` like http://jsfiddle.net/0nf8x1r2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run this code. I just used 100% pure javaScript due to I have no work to do at this moment :) but If I need functionality like that, I will surely use jquery fadeIn() and fadeOut() methods.*( Note :  This can be easily done with jquery or with pure css & some 2, 3 lines of JS)* :)

```html
<button>click</button>
<div class='imgContainer'><img id='img' src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1556757758-bcaf8510b51d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" style="opacity: 1 ; display: block;" alt=""></div>
<script>
 const button = document.querySelector('button');
 const imgContainer = document.querySelector('.imgContainer');

 button.addEventListener('click' , () => {
 const styleAttr = imgContainer.childNodes[0].attributes[2].nodeValue;
 const splitAttr = styleAttr.split(';');
 let opacity = Number(splitAttr[0].split(':')[1]);

 if(opacity > 0){
  let i = opacity
  const interval1 = setInterval(changeImg, 20);
  function changeImg(){
   if( i > 0){
    const newStyle = 'opacity: '+ i + '; display: block';
    imgContainer.childNodes[0].attributes[2].nodeValue = newStyle
    i = i - 0.1;
   }
   if( i < 0){
    clearInterval(interval1);
    i = 0;

    const firstImg = 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1556757758-bcaf8510b51d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60'
    const secondImg = 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1556644326-3b615a8ebed8?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60'

    let currentUrl = imgContainer.childNodes[0].attributes[1].nodeValue 
    if( currentUrl == firstImg ){
     imgContainer.childNodes[0].attributes[1].nodeValue = secondImg
    }
    if( currentUrl == secondImg ){
     imgContainer.childNodes[0].attributes[1].nodeValue = firstImg
    }
          
    const newStyle = 'opacity: 0 ; display: none'
    imgContainer.childNodes[0].attributes[2].nodeValue = newStyle
    const interval2 = setInterval(increaseOpacity, 20); 

    function increaseOpacity(){
     if( i >= 0 && i < 1 ){
      const newStyle = 'opacity: '+ i + '; display: block';
      imgContainer.childNodes[0].attributes[2].nodeValue = newStyle
      i = i + 0.1;
     }
     if( i >= 1 ){
      const newStyle = 'opacity: 1 ; display: block'
      imgContainer.childNodes[0].attributes[2].nodeValue = newStyle
      clearInterval(interval2);
     }
    }
   }      
  }
 }
    })
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

No, this can't be done if you change the `src` attribute. There are however other ways to do this. You can use two image elements on to of each other and animate the `opacity` css property, or you can create a div and set the `background-image` property.

```js
function changeImage1() {
  var img = document.getElementById("myimg1")
  img.style.opacity = 0;
}

function changeImage2() {
  var img = document.getElementById("myimg2")
  img.style.backgroundImage = 'url("https://cdn.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_asset/file/10675351/The_Verge_Cubeometry_Wallpaper_Portrait.0.png")'
}
```

```css
#imgContainer {
  position: relative;
}

#myimg1 {
  transition: opacity 5s;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#myimg2 {
  background-image: url("https://cdn.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_asset/file/10675417/The_Verge_Singularity_Wallpaper_Portrait.0.png");
  background-size: contain;
  transition: background-image 5s;
  width: 100px;
  height: calc(100px * 3840 / 2160);
}
```

```html
<h1>Option 1</h1>

<div id="imgContainer">
  <img src="https://cdn.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_asset/file/10675351/The_Verge_Cubeometry_Wallpaper_Portrait.0.png" width="100">
  <img id="myimg1" src="https://cdn.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_asset/file/10675417/The_Verge_Singularity_Wallpaper_Portrait.0.png" width="100">
</div>
<button onclick="changeImage1()">Change</button>

<h1>Option 2<h1>

<div id="myimg2"></div>
<button onclick="changeImage2()">Change</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one using jquery fadeIn and fadeOut functions also you can change the delay

```js
$("#link").click(function() {
    $("#image").fadeOut(1000, function() {
        $("#image").attr("src",$("#link").attr("href"));
    }).fadeIn(1000);
    return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="image" src="http://www.google.com/logos/2011/trevithick11-hp.jpg"/>
<a id="link" href="http://www.google.com/logos/2011/mothersday11-hp.jpg">Change picture</a>
```